# Duplicating and Transforming Data in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of football results. It is laid out in date order with a row for each game. Each row contains the name of the home team and away team in different columns along with the result.

I want to create a new dataframe that contains a series of all the games played by each team (home and away) in a column called "Team", a separate column for the Opponent and a third column for the Result.

Here's an example of the original dataframe:

| Date | Home | Away | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sunday, 21 May 2017, 15:00 | A | B | A |
| Thursday, 18 May 2017, 19:45 | C | D | D |
| Wednesday, 17 May 2017, 19:45 | E | A | E |
| Tuesday, 16 May 2017, 20:00 | B | C | Draw |

And this is what I want to achieve:

| Date | Team | Opponent | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sunday, 21 May 2017, 15:00 | A | B | A |
| Wednesday, 17 May 2017, 19:45 | A | E | E |
| Sunday, 21 May 2017, 15:00 | B | A | A |
| Tuesday, 16 May 2017, 20:00 | B | C | Draw |
| Tuesday, 16 May 2017, 20:00 | C | B | Draw |
| Thursday, 18 May 2017, 19:45 | C | D | D |
| Thursday, 18 May 2017, 19:45 | D | C | D |
| Wednesday, 17 May 2017, 19:45 | E | A | E |

I am new to Pandas and don't know where to start with this. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can swap the names with [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) and [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), optionally [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
out = (pd.concat([df, df.rename(columns={'Home': 'Away', 'Away': 'Home'})])
         .sort_values(by=['Home', 'Away'], ignore_index=True)
      )
```

Output:

```
                            Date Home Away Result
0     Sunday, 21 May 2017, 15:00    A    B      A
1  Wednesday, 17 May 2017, 19:45    A    E      E
2     Sunday, 21 May 2017, 15:00    B    A      A
3    Tuesday, 16 May 2017, 20:00    B    C   Draw
4    Tuesday, 16 May 2017, 20:00    C    B   Draw
5   Thursday, 18 May 2017, 19:45    C    D      D
6   Thursday, 18 May 2017, 19:45    D    C      D
7  Wednesday, 17 May 2017, 19:45    E    A      E
```

Comment: Hi @mozway, this is grreat, thanks. One follow-up question: is there a way of identifying in the new df which column the team was originally in? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can add keys to concat to get an extra index level. In this case make sure to reset it to columns before sorting (or remove the `ignore_index=True`)